# disable wordpress canonical tag meta

Tags: headers

wordpress core automatically generates canonical tag in **HEAD** section:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://blabla.com" />
```

how to disable/remove that?

Answer (score 16):

found solution: before **wp_head()** command, insert:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');
```

p.s. if generator meta tag is being added from elsewhere (i.e. from theme or plugin, rather than wp-core) and was priority other than 10, then you might need to put the exact priority, as is was given from that theme/plugin:

```
i.e. remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical', 47);
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ this works.

Comment: This didn't work for me, can you please help

Comment: @HariSwaminathan: many plugins may also generate rel=canonical links.  Try turning plugins off (or looking at their code) to see if that helps.

Comment: @DeniseDraper Thanks, I had tried disabling the plugins and found the issue.

Comment: Not officially on topic of this question, but `remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head');` might frequently be a good accompaniment to this to remove `<link rel="shortlink"...` too.

Comment: @squarecandy thanks, but it was good you also mentioned, why removing `shortlink` is good for site or seo?

Comment: It has little or no effect on SEO, as most wordpress setups have the `/?p=1234` set to redirect to the regular URL. It's just a personal thing - I don't like the look of the short urls the way WordPress automatically does them, and sometimes they are not even shorter than the original like `/about/` vs `?p=13243` so I would prefer not to broadcast that to the world as the official shortlink for the page.